# Cannot resolve overloaded method map Scala 2.10.12/Intellij 2019.2.2

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

```
def saveOffsetRanges(offsetRanges: ListBuffer[OffsetRange], consumer: String): Unit = {

println(s"offsets to redis${offsetRanges}")

val client = JedisUtil.getClient()

val map = offsetRanges
  .groupBy(_.topic)
    .map{ // errors found : cannot resolve overloaded method 
      case (topic , offsets) =>
        val partitionToOffset = offsets.map(info => {
          info.partition.toString() -> info.untilOffset.toString
        })

        Serialization.write(partitionToOffset)
    }

client.close()


}
```

Idea errors found: cannot resolve overloaded method 'map', but 'map' is very common in scala. And i am sure the code is correct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRnk3.png)

Then I tried to invalidate cache and restart( IDEA -> File -> Invalide Caches/Restart). The problem still exists and other 'map' also mentioned cannot resolve, before i operate, other 'map' is ok.

```
  def getOffsets(consumer: String) = {

val client = JedisUtil.getClient()

client.hgetAll(s"offset_$consumer")
  .asScala
  .map{// errors found : cannot resolve overloaded method 
    case (partition,offset) =>
      val tp = new TopicPartition(partition.toInt)
      val o = offset.toLong
      tp->o
  }
 }
```

It is really wired, code could work but the errors effect the coding(idea don't automatic prompt method and type )

Comment: Both Scala 2.10 and IntelliJ 2019.2.2 are very old. Since then there were many bug fixes both to Scala and to IntelliJ. I'd recommend to upgrade both. But just for making sure that it is an IDE issue, you can run `sbt +test` from your command lime and verify it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, finally i found the reason is my project library has 2 scala, removed all and readd scala, fixed.